# Css height/min-height 100% window

Tags: html, css

Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id"content">
            Some random content
        </div>
        <div id="footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width:960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
}
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Problem:
For what I have been reading, this code should do the height of the content div take all the height of the window even if the content it's smaller. The problem is that it makes it take more than the window height, even with a very small content.

I don't understand how the content can take more than 100% height and how can I fix it.

Comment: What you've written is a bit confusing, how about an example on www.codepen.io ?

Comment: so do you want the content div to be the height of the contents?  What is your objective?

Comment: My goal is: if the content is smaller than the window height, the div should take the window height. If its bigger than the window height, the div takes the div height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working fine, you're misunderstanding how it should work. You have header and footer set to 100px so the site is actually adding 200px to the entire page.

If that is a copy and paste you have html errors too, your content div is missing an= sign and the footer div is missing the closing "

What you want is a wrapper and position fixed on the footer not relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/ghDUd/1/

Comment: Aaah ok. Thanks for the explanation. Get it now =)!

Answer (score 0):

it take more than 100% because the header is having 100px as well, so the page has a 100%+100px total height, put the header inside the content wrap, that would be a quick-fix

Answer (score 0):

Assuming proper code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        html {
height: 100%;
}
body{
width:960px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#header{
height: 100px;
}
#content{
min-height: 100%;
}
#footer{
height: 100px;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
        <body>
           <div id="header">
           </div>
           <div id="content">
               Some random content
           </div>
           <div id="footer">
           </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`content` div does have 100% of window height. That means it ends 100px (`header`'s height) below window height. If you want footer to be always on the bottom, you should use `position: fixed; bottom: 0` on footer.